# Imagick composite produces large output filesize

Tags: php, imagick

I've spent several hours trying to discover how after Imagick composes an image atop of another that `7.97KB + 98.39KB = 725.49KB`, when you'd expect 1/8th of that.

```php
$outputLocation = 'output.png';

$mask = new \Imagick('mask.png');
$overlay = new \Imagick('overlay.png');

$overlay->resizeImage(800, 600, \Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$overlay->compositeImage($mask, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0, \Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);

$overlay->writeImage($outputLocation );
$mask->destroy();
$overlay->destroy();
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can dramatically reduce the output size? As these images are intended for web and the input files are small, I was expecting around the 50KB-100KB mark or thereabouts.

Appreciate your time, thanks

Edit: I've added the output of `$imagick->identifyImage()` below each image and note that units become Pixels Per Centimeter when the input is "Undefined??" + "PPI". Not exactly sure what I'm looking at when I read 99% of it so hoping it helps with a solution

> Mask: (7.97KB)

[image: Mask]

```
Image: /Uploads/5d28298a46/dm-full.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 800x600+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: PaletteAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 480000
    Red:
      min: 52 (0.203922)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 231.186 (0.90661)
      standard deviation: 65.3238 (0.256172)
      kurtosis: 3.65714
      skewness: -2.37848
      entropy: 0.521586
    Green:
      min: 52 (0.203922)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 231.186 (0.90661)
      standard deviation: 65.3238 (0.256172)
      kurtosis: 3.65714
      skewness: -2.37848
      entropy: 0.521586
    Blue:
      min: 49 (0.192157)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 230.834 (0.90523)
      standard deviation: 66.2892 (0.259958)
      kurtosis: 3.65714
      skewness: -2.37848
      entropy: 0.521586
    Alpha:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 29.7496 (0.116665)
      standard deviation: 81.772 (0.320674)
      kurtosis: 3.70517
      skewness: -2.38776
      entropy: 0.549454
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 229.614 (0.900446)
      standard deviation: 70.0274 (0.274617)
      kurtosis: 4.09826
      skewness: -2.44298
      entropy: 0.528553
  Alpha: srgba(255,255,255,0)   #FFFFFF00
  Colors: 132
  Histogram:
     55331: ( 52, 52, 49,255) #343431FF srgba(52,52,49,1)
        87: ( 52, 52, 49,254) #343431FE srgba(52,52,49,0.996078)
        47: ( 52, 52, 49,253) #343431FD srgba(52,52,49,0.992157)
        46: ( 52, 52, 49,252) #343431FC srgba(52,52,49,0.988235)
        27: ( 52, 52, 49, 12) #3434310C srgba(52,52,49,0.0470588)
        24: ( 52, 52, 49,248) #343431F8 srgba(52,52,49,0.972549)
        23: ( 52, 52, 49,249) #343431F9 srgba(52,52,49,0.976471)
        22: ( 52, 52, 49,251) #343431FB srgba(52,52,49,0.984314)
        18: ( 52, 52, 49,233) #343431E9 srgba(52,52,49,0.913725)
        17: ( 52, 52, 49,215) #343431D7 srgba(52,52,49,0.843137)
        17: ( 52, 52, 49, 34) #34343122 srgba(52,52,49,0.133333)
        16: ( 52, 52, 49,  8) #34343108 srgba(52,52,49,0.0313725)
        15: ( 52, 52, 49,  4) #34343104 srgba(52,52,49,0.0156863)
        14: ( 52, 52, 49,245) #343431F5 srgba(52,52,49,0.960784)
        13: ( 52, 52, 49,238) #343431EE srgba(52,52,49,0.933333)
        12: ( 52, 52, 49,236) #343431EC srgba(52,52,49,0.92549)
        12: ( 52, 52, 49,229) #343431E5 srgba(52,52,49,0.898039)
        12: ( 52, 52, 49, 48) #34343130 srgba(52,52,49,0.188235)
        12: ( 52, 52, 49, 38) #34343126 srgba(52,52,49,0.14902)
        11: ( 52, 52, 49,243) #343431F3 srgba(52,52,49,0.952941)
        11: ( 52, 52, 49,240) #343431F0 srgba(52,52,49,0.941176)
        11: ( 52, 52, 49,103) #34343167 srgba(52,52,49,0.403922)
        11: ( 52, 52, 49,100) #34343164 srgba(52,52,49,0.392157)
        10: ( 52, 52, 49,250) #343431FA srgba(52,52,49,0.980392)
        10: ( 52, 52, 49,246) #343431F6 srgba(52,52,49,0.964706)
        10: ( 52, 52, 49,178) #343431B2 srgba(52,52,49,0.698039)
        10: ( 52, 52, 49, 52) #34343134 srgba(52,52,49,0.203922)
         9: ( 52, 52, 49,247) #343431F7 srgba(52,52,49,0.968627)
         9: ( 52, 52, 49,202) #343431CA srgba(52,52,49,0.792157)
         9: ( 52, 52, 49, 71) #34343147 srgba(52,52,49,0.278431)
         9: ( 52, 52, 49, 20) #34343114 srgba(52,52,49,0.0784314)
         9: ( 52, 52, 49, 16) #34343110 srgba(52,52,49,0.0627451)
         8: ( 52, 52, 49,228) #343431E4 srgba(52,52,49,0.894118)
         8: ( 52, 52, 49,199) #343431C7 srgba(52,52,49,0.780392)
         8: ( 52, 52, 49,119) #34343177 srgba(52,52,49,0.466667)
         8: ( 52, 52, 49, 27) #3434311B srgba(52,52,49,0.105882)
         7: ( 52, 52, 49,241) #343431F1 srgba(52,52,49,0.945098)
         7: ( 52, 52, 49,230) #343431E6 srgba(52,52,49,0.901961)
         7: ( 52, 52, 49,220) #343431DC srgba(52,52,49,0.862745)
         7: ( 52, 52, 49,209) #343431D1 srgba(52,52,49,0.819608)
         7: ( 52, 52, 49,194) #343431C2 srgba(52,52,49,0.760784)
         7: ( 52, 52, 49,173) #343431AD srgba(52,52,49,0.678431)
         7: ( 52, 52, 49,162) #343431A2 srgba(52,52,49,0.635294)
         7: ( 52, 52, 49,156) #3434319C srgba(52,52,49,0.611765)
         7: ( 52, 52, 49,134) #34343186 srgba(52,52,49,0.52549)
         7: ( 52, 52, 49, 89) #34343159 srgba(52,52,49,0.34902)
         7: ( 52, 52, 49, 30) #3434311E srgba(52,52,49,0.117647)
         6: ( 52, 52, 49,237) #343431ED srgba(52,52,49,0.929412)
         6: ( 52, 52, 49,227) #343431E3 srgba(52,52,49,0.890196)
         6: ( 52, 52, 49,186) #343431BA srgba(52,52,49,0.729412)
         6: ( 52, 52, 49,176) #343431B0 srgba(52,52,49,0.690196)
         6: ( 52, 52, 49,169) #343431A9 srgba(52,52,49,0.662745)
         6: ( 52, 52, 49,128) #34343180 srgba(52,52,49,0.501961)
         6: ( 52, 52, 49,126) #3434317E srgba(52,52,49,0.494118)
         6: ( 52, 52, 49,114) #34343172 srgba(52,52,49,0.447059)
         6: ( 52, 52, 49,105) #34343169 srgba(52,52,49,0.411765)
         6: ( 52, 52, 49, 98) #34343162 srgba(52,52,49,0.384314)
         6: ( 52, 52, 49, 65) #34343141 srgba(52,52,49,0.254902)
         5: ( 52, 52, 49,242) #343431F2 srgba(52,52,49,0.94902)
         5: ( 52, 52, 49,225) #343431E1 srgba(52,52,49,0.882353)
         5: ( 52, 52, 49,218) #343431DA srgba(52,52,49,0.854902)
         5: ( 52, 52, 49,148) #34343194 srgba(52,52,49,0.580392)
         5: ( 52, 52, 49,140) #3434318C srgba(52,52,49,0.54902)
         5: ( 52, 52, 49,131) #34343183 srgba(52,52,49,0.513725)
         5: ( 52, 52, 49,124) #3434317C srgba(52,52,49,0.486275)
         5: ( 52, 52, 49,117) #34343175 srgba(52,52,49,0.458824)
         5: ( 52, 52, 49, 44) #3434312C srgba(52,52,49,0.172549)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,234) #343431EA srgba(52,52,49,0.917647)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,226) #343431E2 srgba(52,52,49,0.886275)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,224) #343431E0 srgba(52,52,49,0.878431)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,223) #343431DF srgba(52,52,49,0.87451)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,217) #343431D9 srgba(52,52,49,0.85098)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,214) #343431D6 srgba(52,52,49,0.839216)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,213) #343431D5 srgba(52,52,49,0.835294)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,206) #343431CE srgba(52,52,49,0.807843)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,203) #343431CB srgba(52,52,49,0.796078)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,200) #343431C8 srgba(52,52,49,0.784314)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,188) #343431BC srgba(52,52,49,0.737255)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,182) #343431B6 srgba(52,52,49,0.713725)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,180) #343431B4 srgba(52,52,49,0.705882)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,168) #343431A8 srgba(52,52,49,0.658824)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,165) #343431A5 srgba(52,52,49,0.647059)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,154) #3434319A srgba(52,52,49,0.603922)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,145) #34343191 srgba(52,52,49,0.568627)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,111) #3434316F srgba(52,52,49,0.435294)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49,109) #3434316D srgba(52,52,49,0.427451)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49, 92) #3434315C srgba(52,52,49,0.360784)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49, 84) #34343154 srgba(52,52,49,0.329412)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49, 80) #34343150 srgba(52,52,49,0.313725)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49, 77) #3434314D srgba(52,52,49,0.301961)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49, 74) #3434314A srgba(52,52,49,0.290196)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49, 68) #34343144 srgba(52,52,49,0.266667)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49, 42) #3434312A srgba(52,52,49,0.164706)
         4: ( 52, 52, 49, 24) #34343118 srgba(52,52,49,0.0941176)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,239) #343431EF srgba(52,52,49,0.937255)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,235) #343431EB srgba(52,52,49,0.921569)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,231) #343431E7 srgba(52,52,49,0.905882)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,216) #343431D8 srgba(52,52,49,0.847059)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,210) #343431D2 srgba(52,52,49,0.823529)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,207) #343431CF srgba(52,52,49,0.811765)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,197) #343431C5 srgba(52,52,49,0.772549)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,196) #343431C4 srgba(52,52,49,0.768627)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,185) #343431B9 srgba(52,52,49,0.72549)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,171) #343431AB srgba(52,52,49,0.670588)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,166) #343431A6 srgba(52,52,49,0.65098)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,152) #34343198 srgba(52,52,49,0.596078)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,142) #3434318E srgba(52,52,49,0.556863)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,135) #34343187 srgba(52,52,49,0.529412)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49,121) #34343179 srgba(52,52,49,0.47451)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49, 86) #34343156 srgba(52,52,49,0.337255)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49, 62) #3434313E srgba(52,52,49,0.243137)
         3: ( 52, 52, 49, 58) #3434313A srgba(52,52,49,0.227451)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,244) #343431F4 srgba(52,52,49,0.956863)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,232) #343431E8 srgba(52,52,49,0.909804)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,222) #343431DE srgba(52,52,49,0.870588)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,221) #343431DD srgba(52,52,49,0.866667)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,211) #343431D3 srgba(52,52,49,0.827451)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,201) #343431C9 srgba(52,52,49,0.788235)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,193) #343431C1 srgba(52,52,49,0.756863)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,191) #343431BF srgba(52,52,49,0.74902)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,183) #343431B7 srgba(52,52,49,0.717647)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,175) #343431AF srgba(52,52,49,0.686275)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,161) #343431A1 srgba(52,52,49,0.631373)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,159) #3434319F srgba(52,52,49,0.623529)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,147) #34343193 srgba(52,52,49,0.576471)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49,138) #3434318A srgba(52,52,49,0.541176)
         2: ( 52, 52, 49, 55) #34343137 srgba(52,52,49,0.215686)
         1: ( 52, 52, 49,205) #343431CD srgba(52,52,49,0.803922)
         1: ( 52, 52, 49,190) #343431BE srgba(52,52,49,0.745098)
         1: ( 52, 52, 49,151) #34343197 srgba(52,52,49,0.592157)
         1: ( 52, 52, 49, 95) #3434315F srgba(52,52,49,0.372549)
    423690: (255,255,255,  0) #FFFFFF00 srgba(255,255,255,0)
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgba(223,223,223,1)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 800x600+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2019-01-17T17:28:42-07:00
    date:modify: 2019-01-17T17:28:42-07:00
    png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 8
    png:IHDR.bit_depth: 8
    png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 6
    png:IHDR.color_type: 6 (RGBA)
    png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
    png:IHDR.width,height: 800, 600
    png:sRGB: intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)
    png:text: 1 tEXt/zTXt/iTXt chunks were found
    signature: 66726c0234cca3a421acd3f8b0a26bb208aa027de7e96f629ab886f9811e8ba2
    Software: Adobe ImageReady
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 7.97KB
  Number pixels: 480K
  Pixels per second: 9.6MB
  User time: 0.040u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.049
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.4-10 Q16 x86_64 2017-11-14 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

> Overlay: (98.39KB)

[image: Overlay]

```
Image: /Uploads/66e0704554/rip1.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 640x480+0+0
  Resolution: 96x96
  Print size: 6.66667x5
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 307200
    Red:
      min: 59 (0.231373)
      max: 241 (0.945098)
      mean: 138.879 (0.544625)
      standard deviation: 43.3873 (0.170146)
      kurtosis: -1.00018
      skewness: 0.474575
      entropy: 0.959705
    Green:
      min: 56 (0.219608)
      max: 223 (0.87451)
      mean: 133.056 (0.521788)
      standard deviation: 38.0973 (0.149401)
      kurtosis: -0.944014
      skewness: 0.443263
      entropy: 0.958768
    Blue:
      min: 57 (0.223529)
      max: 213 (0.835294)
      mean: 128.22 (0.502823)
      standard deviation: 34.149 (0.133917)
      kurtosis: -0.889802
      skewness: 0.384749
      entropy: 0.95673
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 56 (0.219608)
      max: 241 (0.945098)
      mean: 133.385 (0.523079)
      standard deviation: 38.7299 (0.151882)
      kurtosis: -0.730287
      skewness: 0.517232
      entropy: 0.958401
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 640x480+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 90
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    comment: CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 90

    date:create: 2019-01-17T18:51:23-07:00
    date:modify: 2019-01-17T07:02:14-07:00
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 1x1,1x1,1x1
    signature: 18b3909f043cc43ed544dc1186c2bf12e82d754b25ce79d9f751711bca0bb9e5
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 98.4KB
  Number pixels: 307K
  Pixels per second: 30.72MB
  User time: 0.010u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.009
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.4-10 Q16 x86_64 2017-11-14 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

> Output: **(725.49KB!!)**

[image]

```
Image: /Uploads/full-vest-ucp-digital-camouflage-ripstop.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 800x600+0+0
  Resolution: 37.79x37.79
  Print size: 21.1696x15.8772
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  Type: TrueColorAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 480000
    Red:
      min: 59 (0.231373)
      max: 242 (0.94902)
      mean: 138.88 (0.544628)
      standard deviation: 43.3913 (0.170162)
      kurtosis: -1.0001
      skewness: 0.474861
      entropy: 0.959552
    Green:
      min: 57 (0.223529)
      max: 222 (0.870588)
      mean: 133.055 (0.521786)
      standard deviation: 38.1002 (0.149413)
      kurtosis: -0.94345
      skewness: 0.443572
      entropy: 0.958694
    Blue:
      min: 57 (0.223529)
      max: 213 (0.835294)
      mean: 128.22 (0.502822)
      standard deviation: 34.1488 (0.133917)
      kurtosis: -0.88896
      skewness: 0.385181
      entropy: 0.956701
    Alpha:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 29.7496 (0.116665)
      standard deviation: 81.772 (0.320674)
      kurtosis: 3.70517
      skewness: -2.38776
      entropy: 0.0731075
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 156.351 (0.613143)
      standard deviation: 52.8848 (0.207392)
      kurtosis: 2.60166
      skewness: 0.242498
      entropy: 0.737014
  Alpha: srgba(139,135,130,0)   #8B878200
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.45455
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgba(223,223,223,1)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 800x600+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    comment: CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 90

    date:create: 2019-01-17T21:30:04-07:00
    date:modify: 2019-01-17T21:30:04-07:00
    png:bKGD: chunk was found (see Background color, above)
    png:cHRM: chunk was found (see Chromaticity, above)
    png:gAMA: gamma=0.45454544 (See Gamma, above)
    png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 8
    png:IHDR.bit_depth: 8
    png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 6
    png:IHDR.color_type: 6 (RGBA)
    png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
    png:IHDR.width,height: 800, 600
    png:pHYs: x_res=3779, y_res=3779, units=1
    png:sRGB: intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)
    png:text: 3 tEXt/zTXt/iTXt chunks were found
    png:tIME: 2019-01-17T07:02:14Z
    signature: 9466b41c1f7bea9638e3cda09749e796df0f594fbf5b152060e2ecd671ef80fd
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 725KB
  Number pixels: 480K
  Pixels per second: 24MB
  User time: 0.030u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.019
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.4-10 Q16 x86_64 2017-11-14 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Comment: What is the resolution of the output image?

Comment: I updated the question to include information printed out about each image, hopefully that helps :x

Comment: You have converted from palette alpha on your input to true color alpha on the output. The former is 8-bit and the latter is 32-bit. So if you want to preserve the input palette alpha then add the prefix PNG8: to your output image. `$outputLocation = 'PNG8:output.png'`

Comment: Thanks, that reduced it massively - although the quality of the output is less than desirable - i'll keep chatting to you on Imagick forums and you can post your solution here for a tick <3

Comment: You can also make the background under the transparent areas a constant black using the equivalent of -background black -alpha background after putting your mask into the alpha channel. That will reduce size also

Comment: So the best result ended up being PNG32, after posterising and despeckling i'm still left with semi-hd quality, smooth edges. Despeckling was how I got the size from 750k down to 124k which is suitable as I used a HD image for test purposes. PNG8 was great but unfortunately I couldn't resolve the damaged pixels and rough edges

Answer (score 0):

Ok so all things said and done, ultimately my solution was simply just

```
$outputLocation = 'output.png';
$mask = new \Imagick('mask.png');
$overlay = new \Imagick('overlay.png');
$overlay->resizeImage(800, 600, \Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$overlay->compositeImage($mask, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0, \Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);

// Significantly reduced image size whilst retaining decent quality
$overlay->posterizeImage(15, false);
$overlay->despeckleImage();
///////////////////////////

$overlay->writeImage($outputLocation);
```

and outputting as `PNG32`

This cut size down from 750KB~ to 124KB~ for testing purposes I used a bright colorful flower and below is my end result:

[image]